# extend a class using a host class but not inheritance

Tags: c++

I would like to create a thin host class of a specific class to extend a specific functionality but not necessarily inheriting it. For example, class Base is described as:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void func_1();
    void func_2();
    ...
    void func_n();
};
```

class Base1 will inherit Base but store a pointer of Base

```
class Base1 : public Base
{
public:
    void func_1()
    {
        mpBase->func_1();
        // do something else
    }
private:
    Base* mpBase;
}
```

Is there a way to automatically invoke mpBase->func_2 to func_n for Base1 because they are basically the same (n can be a large number)? Using pointer it is not done automatically. The reason I want to do it because I want to extend func_1 for all possible inherited classes of Base, without creating Base1 for every inherited classes.

Best

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. This is what inheritance is for, and this is how it's done in C++. Additionally, if a class has individual methods named "func1" through "func100", or something like that, that strongly indicates that the class is not designed correctly, and there's probably a much better way to restructure and redesign the class, that will solve both problems.

Comment: Inheritance is certainly the easier way to do this. Wrapping via composition and duplicating is pointless work.

Comment: @sweenish let's say Base has 2 children, Child1 and Child2. And func_1 of Child1 and Child2 need to be extended in the same way. What can be done, 2 subclasses for Child1 and Child2?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've seen the func01 - funcnn, the justification was debugging a very complex algorithm. I agree with you, but it's definitely something that's out there. Having been in both industry and academia, industry needs to stop pretending that they're that much better. I've seen the hot garbage that they write while also mocking the code intended to teach a principle, not be used in production.

Comment: It's hard to give a good answer without understanding the conceptual model behind the classes. `Base` is fine to explain which class inherits from which, but it doesn't tell us what the classes are meant to represent.

Comment: It might be, however, that you need to extract out the shared functions into an abstract base class, which declares `virtual void func_1() = 0` (pure virtual), but implements `func_2` through `func_n`, then you can have two children which each implement `func_1` differently

Comment: @TallChuck the situation is like this: Base exists and has lots of children. I would like to extend the func_1 of all children at once without creating subclass for each of them. Another way is to templatize Base1 but it is harder to use because one has to find a way to detect corresponding Children at runtime.

Comment: @Kstn, can you clarify your use of the term "children"? Usually "child" is used as a synonym for "subclass". Do you mean "instance"?

Comment: @Kstn You insert an inheritance level between Base and the Children that need this common extension. `Base -> extension -> Child1, Child2` Child1 and Child2 now inherit from extension.

Comment: @TallChuck yes, I mean child is subclass and children subclasses

Comment: @sweenish right, that's another inheritance level. Obviously I do not want to modify func_1 of each Children either.

Comment: So does that mean you have a current implementation that _does_ use many subclasses of `Base`, and you want to refactor it to cut down on this number of subclasses?

Comment: @Kstn You're not? You added it in the extension. All children that derive from the extension now have it. And what's wrong with another inheritance level? It's getting to where I'm about to vote to close for lacking details/clarity.

Comment: You could have a single `Base` class that implements everything _except_ `func_1()`, and provide an object to its constructor to implement `func_1()`

Comment: thanks I'll check out the visitor pattern. @sweenish Child_1 etc is fixed, derived from Base and should not be modified. To have Base1::func_1 functionality it has to be extended for each Child_n. Which is not optimal solution IMO.

Comment: That's a detail that should have been in the question from the beginning, don't you think? I'm also having a hard time finding a good justification for why it can't be modified outside of homework. It's not much of a modification, you just inherit from extension instead of Base, and then you have the behavior that you want. I have now voted to close since it's obvious that all the information needed to provide an adequate answer has not been provided.